# C++ dependent name: Is this typename required?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, dependent-name

In `a.hpp` I defined:

```
#include <utility>
namespace Board {
    template<int W, int H>
    struct GroupNode
    {
        using PointType = std::pair<int, int>;
        // ...
    };
}
```

Then, in `b.cpp` I defined:

```
#include "a.hpp"
namespace Board {
    template<int W, int H>
    struct NodeList
    {
        using StdList = std::list < /* typename */ GroupNode<W, H>>;
    }
}
// and then use NodeList<19, 19> nl;
```

The code above could be compiled on both gcc-6 and clang-3.9 without any warning. 
However, Clion 2016.3 complained `cannot resolve variable GroupNode` in `b.cpp`. Uncommenting `typename` could tame Clion warning, but I was wondering whether this `typename` is required? If so, why g++/clang++ didn't give out any warnings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not required. According to [temp.res]/3 in C++14:

> When a *qualified-id* is intended to refer to a type that is not a member of the current instantiation (14.6.2.1)
>   and its *nested-name-specifier* refers to a dependent type, it shall be prefixed by the keyword `typename`, forming
>   a *typename-specifier* . If the *qualified-id* in a *typename-specifier* does not denote a type, the program is ill-
>   formed.

Here there is no *nested-name-specifier* referring to a dependent type, so `typename` is not required. (*nested-name-specifier* refers to a `::` and the type or namespace to its left. Clearly, `std` is not a type, much less a dependent type.)